# external php file echo variable include html code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook, .htaccess

i have created  get friends list from  facebook. I got answer.i have developed  its code  php code.  finally stored variable in echo variable.Now i want include  php file in html code. i have changed setting created .htaccess file. Now i want  how to include php  echo variable  particular place html ?

```
                          <div class="col-md-6 two">

                                <span>36</span>
                                <p>FRIENDS COUNTR</p>

                            </div>
```

this My html code. i want include  that code inside my php echo file

```
<?php
require '/src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

    $result = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

    print "<pre>";
    //print_r($result);
    $json_output=($result['summary']['total_count']);
     echo "<h2>".'<br>FRIENDS COUNTER<br/>&nbsp'. $json_output. "</h2>";
    print "</pre>";




} else {
  $statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_friends'));
}


?>
```

i have tried  in html page i have include top of the html page looks like

```
 <?php 
  session_start();
 include('facebook.php');
?>
```

value print the top of the page .i want display    this html page?

```
                   <div class="col-md-6 two">

                        <span>36</span>
                        <p>FRIENDS COUNTR</p>

                    </div>
```

how to add echo value in html file? please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
require '/src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));

$app_id =   '{app_id}';
$app_secret = '{app_secret}';

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

    $result = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

    $json_output=($result['summary']['total_count']);
     echo '<div class="col-md-6 two"><span>'.$json_output.'</span><p>FRIENDS COUNTR</p></div>';




} else {
  $statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_friends'));
}
?>
```

Like this?

Comment: same design looks  like     <div class="col-md-6 two">

                        <span>36</span>
                        <p>FRIENDS COUNTR</p>

                      </div>

Comment: but design issues come brother  i have  this code its Working fine echo '<p>Friends</p>'. "<h1>".$json_output. "</h1>";